# How to modify data in a local JSON file IONIC 2

Tags: json, angular, ionic2, local

I am making an app in what I have a JSON file. Each object in the Json file has atribbutes and one of them is "Favorite" which can be either true or false depending on the user choice.
However, I tried to implement the following code so when the user click favorite, that item will have its parameter changed from false to true in order to be able to list only the favorite items later.

```
setFavorite(item) {

if (item.favorito == false) {
  this.storage.set('item.favorito','true').then(() => {
    console.log("Adicionado!");
  });
}


else{
  console.log("Já é Favorito!");
}}}
```

However, it is not modifying the parameter inside the json file.
How can I do this?

Comment: From where are you reading this json file: from the app's package or from the device's file system? If this json is inside your app, you can't change it. If it's in the device's file system, you will have to use a plugin such as the cordova-plugin-file (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/). Anyway, in the code you posted there is no code that 'changes the json' and 'save the json file'.

Comment: Is this a JSON file or it's some JSON formated object whose is saved in localStorage?

Comment: Well, the JSON file is inside the app... This the the path im calling the json from:
getData() {

        var url = "assets/Hinario5CCB.json";
                
        if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.platform.is('android')) {
            url = "/android_asset/www/" + url;
        }

        return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res) => {
            return res.json()
        });
    }
So I think it is inside the app. Inside the folder assets, that is inside the app development folder.